# GKE nodes unexpectedly deleted and recreated

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine. The nodes get deleted/created very often (at least once a day). Even though new instances are created to replace them, and pods are moved to these new nodes, I would like to understand why the nodes disappear.

I checked the settings used to create the cluster and the node pool:

- "Automatic node upgrade" is Disabled on the node pool.
- "Pre-emptible nodes" is Disabled.
- "Automatic node repair" is Enabled, but I doesn't look like there was a node repair, since I don't see anything in `gcloud container operations list` at the time when my nodes were deleted.

I can see that the current nodes were all (re-)created at 21:00, while the cluster was created at 08:35 :

```
➜  ~ gcloud container clusters describe my-cluster --format=json
{
  "createTime": "2019-04-11T08:35:39+00:00",
  ...
  "nodePools": [
    {
      ...
      "management": {
        "autoRepair": true
      },
      "name": "default-pool",
    }
  ],
  "status": "RUNNING",
  ...
}
```

How can I trace the reason why the nodes were deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem by creating a cluster, manually stopping the kubelet on a node (by running `systemctl stop kubelet`) to trigger repair and watching the node recover. In my case, I do see an operation for the auto node repair, but I can also see in the GCE operations log that the VM was deleted and recreated (by the GKE robot account).

If you run `gcloud compute operations list` (or check the [cloud console page](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/compute/operations) for operations) you should see what caused the VM to be deleted and recreated.

Comment: Thanks! Checking operations helped me track down the fact that my nodes were running on [preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms) VMs.